# Can this relation between the Merten's function be simplified?

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, mobius-inversion, mobius-function

### Question

Can this relationship be simplified further? $ \def\lf{\left\lfloor}   \def\rf{\right\rfloor} $

$$  \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(i)(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf \ln(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1)   + \lf \frac{n}{i} \rf \ln(i) + \int_0^\infty \frac{2 \tan^{-1}(t/(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1))}{e^{2 \pi t} -1}dt)=1 +(1-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi)) M(n) $$

### Derivation

Using the Mobius inversion formula on the factorial function and the floor function I obtained the following identity:
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n (i^{\lf \frac{n}{i} \rf} \lf \frac{n}{i}\rf !)^{\mu(i)} = 1$$

$$ \implies \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(i)(\ln\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf ! + \lf \frac{n}{i} \rf \ln(i)) =0 $$

$$ \implies \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(i)(\ln\Gamma(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1) + \lf \frac{n}{i} \rf \ln(i)) =0 $$

Using Stirling's formula

$$ \implies \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(i)(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1)(\ln(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1) -(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1) +\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi)- \frac{1}{2}\ln((\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1) + \lf \frac{n}{i} \rf \ln(i)) + \int_0^\infty \frac{2 \tan^{-1}(t/(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1))}{e^{2 \pi t} -1})=0 $$

Expanding terms and using the mobius inversion formula on $ \sum 1 = n \implies \sum \mu(i) \lf \frac{n}{i}\rf = 1  $

Where $M(n)$ is the Mertens function:

$$ \implies \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(i)(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf \ln(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1)   + \lf \frac{n}{i} \rf \ln(i) + \int_0^\infty \frac{2 \tan^{-1}(t/(\lf \frac{n}{i}\rf + 1))}{e^{2 \pi t} -1}dt)=1 +(1-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2 \pi)) M(n) $$

P.S: I'm only a physics undergraduate

Comment: you should look at $\zeta(s)$ and his friends. and for which term is that integral ? it is for $\ln \Gamma(s+1)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I got the integral from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function

Comment: so no it cannot be simplified in the sense that its best simplification is your first formula.  the only thing you can hope to get by playing with Dirichlet (multiplicative) convolution is a non-trivial bound on one of those terms. in the same way that $|\mu(n)| = 0$ or $1$ is non-trivial and obtained from the Euler product ($\mu$ being defined as the convolutive inverse of $1$ the sequence with only ones )